# Which way of removing elements from an ArrayList is more efficient?

Tags: java, arraylist

I have the following declarations:

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add("1");
list.add("2");
list.add("2");
list.add("3");
list.add("4");
```

Now my question is: if I want to remove the "2"s from the list, which way is better?

first way:

```
for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
    if(list.get(i).equals("2")) {
        list.remove(i);
        i--;
    }
}
```

second way:

```
Iterator<String> iterator = list.iterator();
    while(iterator.hasNext())
        if(iterator.next().equals("2"))
            iterator.remove();
```

Are both safed properly and which is more efficient?

Are there any other methods to remove elements from an ArrayList without getting `IndexOutOfBounds` errors?

Comment: second one is more clear

Comment: Make use of the `contains()` method to impose some condition.

Comment: If you want efficient removal from the middle of the list, you shouldn't be using `ArrayList`. Maybe `LinkedList`.

Comment: Okay, great, I'll check out `LinkedList`.

Comment: BTW, they're essentially the same exact thing. The second way is pretty much "syntax sugar". However, they do the same thing.

Answer (score 5):

Actually, what might be faster is

```
list.removeAll(Collections.singleton("2"));
```

Behind the scenes, for an `ArrayList`, it does basically create a new copy of the array like @Edmund suggests, but at a lower level, which may lead to higher performance.

Still, as others have mentioned, a `LinkedList` generally has better performance for removing multiple elements from a large list.

(Even if you do decide to switch to a `LinkedList` you can still use the above code, it will be equivalent to using the iterator method with a little bit of overhead for the singleton collection that's created and for some extra method calls that happen.)

Answer (score 2):

Either way is going to need to shift elements down for each element removed.  If your list is really big, it could well be faster to create a new list:

```
ArrayList<String> newList = new ArrayList<String>();
Iterator<String> iterator = list.iterator();
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    String val = iterator.next();
    if(!val.equals("2"))
        newList.add(val);
}

/* Or just return newList, depending on how list is used in subsequent code. */
list.clear();
list.addAll(newList);
```

You could think about using `LinkedList` instead of `ArrayList`.  But benchmarking (with realistic use cases) is the best way to find out what's most efficient.

Comment: You are right. The best approach is use "add" to a new list instead of "remove" from old list.

Answer (score 0):

For individual elements, your for-loop will work fine <s>(well, it will when you remove `i--` - the `remove()` automatically shifts elements over to the left)</s> (No really, it will work fine).  So will your iteration method.

You're only iterating to the end of the `ArrayList`, and you won't step off of it.  In terms of efficiency, it's a wash - I would recommend you sample runtimes with sizes of 100,000 and see how it goes.  (It's still on the order of O(N) operations, no matter how large the list is.)

Comment: What do you mean "step off of it"? There is nothing wrong with the iterator example.

Comment: @ChristofferHammarström: By "step off", I mean that the OP will avoid ArrayIndexOutOfBounds exceptions, which is something they were concerned about, if you iterate between its length or use the Iterator.

Comment: I added `i--` because if it wasn't decremented, the loop would skip one of the "2"s.

Comment: @GeorgeHerbert:  Noticing that now.  Fair enough!

Answer (score -1):

I have read it in some data structure book, that iterator approach is better,

in case of list.remove call under loop, evety time it will start from 0 index to index ot item to remove, then remove element and shift affected elements, it will be o(n2) process.

but in case of iterator.remove, element are removed as they are accessed by iterator without having to go back at beggining of list, thus o(n) process.

Comment: That only applies for a linked list like `LinkedList`, not an array-backed list like `ArrayList`.